# Mismatched colors on UINavigationBar and UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Quite simply, I'm having issues with making exactly-colored Navigation and Search bars. **Neither of these elements are transparent.**
Here is a screenshot and relevant code.

[image]

Relevant code:

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    let navigationBar = navigationController!.navigationBar

    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setFillColor(UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)
    context.fill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)

    navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
    searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor



    tblFriends.delegate = self
    tblFriends.dataSource = self

    tblFriends.register(UINib(nibName: "FriendCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "FriendCell")
```

I'm manually setting the background image of the navigation bar in order to remove the shadowImage between the two elements.

The color in question SHOULD be 86,200,246. But neither element is that, and both are mismatched. And again, neither element is transparent. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined Joe's code and my own to come up with a working solution for iOS 10.

```
let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.setFillColor(UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)
context.fill(rect)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//To change Navigation Background colour.
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

//To change SearchBar Background colour.
self.searchBar.isTranslucent = false
self.searchBar.backgroundImage = image
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
searchBar.layer.borderColor  = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
    // To Get transparent navigationBar
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)

    //To remove black hairline under the Navigationbar
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()  
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    //To apply your tint background to navigationBar
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    //To remove border and background colour on searchBar
    self.searchbar.isTranslucent = false
    self.searchbar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

    //To apply border and background colour on searchBar
    searchbar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    searchbar.layer.borderColor  = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

**Note:** If you using searchBar as a tableview header.You may need different approach.let me know..

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: iOS version may be affecting things; I'm on iOS10, and the above code gives me a default colorless search bar. Removing "self.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()" makes the color accurate, but adds a black line between the search and navigation bars.

Comment: Above screenshot actually from my  iPhone 6s Plus running iOS 10.0.1 .it should be something else...I will update my code with clear description...thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Easy solution for iOS 10 (iOS 7+):**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

self.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
self.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.10, green:0.58, blue:0.84, alpha:1.0)
self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.10, green:0.58, blue:0.84, alpha:1.0).cgColor
```

[image: Screenshot]